# Big differences in GCC code generation when compiling as C++ vs C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, x86-64

I've been playing around a little bit with x86-64 assembly trying to learn more about the various SIMD extensions that are available (MMX, SSE, AVX).

In order to see how different C or C++ constructs are translated into machine code by GCC I've been using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org) which is a superb tool.

During one of my 'play sessions' I wanted to see how GCC could optimize a simple run-time initialization of an integer array. In this case I tried to write the numbers 0 to 2047 to an array of 2048 unsigned integers.

The code looks as follows:

```
unsigned int buffer[2048];

void setup()
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2048; ++i)
  {
    buffer[i] = i;
  }
}
```

If I enable optimizations and AVX-512 instructions `-O3 -mavx512f -mtune=intel` GCC 6.3 generates some really clever code :)

```
setup():
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:buffer
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:buffer+8192
        vmovdqa64       zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        vmovdqa64       zmm1, ZMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
.L2:
        vmovdqa64       ZMMWORD PTR [rax], zmm0
        add     rax, 64
        cmp     rdx, rax
        vpaddd  zmm0, zmm0, zmm1
        jne     .L2
        ret
buffer:
        .zero   8192
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   1
        .long   2
        .long   3
        .long   4
        .long   5
        .long   6
        .long   7
        .long   8
        .long   9
        .long   10
        .long   11
        .long   12
        .long   13
        .long   14
        .long   15
.LC1:
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
        .long   16
```

However, when I tested what would be generated if the same code was compiled using the GCC C-compiler by adding the flags `-x c` I was really surprised.

I expected similar, if not identical, results but the C-compiler seems to generate **much** more complicated and presumably also much slower machine code. The resulting assembly is too large to paste here in full, but it can be viewed at godbolt.org by following [this](https://godbolt.org/g/A8bRxj) link.

A snippet of the generated code, lines 58 to 83, can be seen below:

```
.L2:
        vpbroadcastd    zmm0, r8d
        lea     rsi, buffer[0+rcx*4]
        vmovdqa64       zmm1, ZMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        vpaddd  zmm0, zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        xor     ecx, ecx
.L4:
        add     ecx, 1
        add     rsi, 64
        vmovdqa64       ZMMWORD PTR [rsi-64], zmm0
        cmp     ecx, edi
        vpaddd  zmm0, zmm0, zmm1
        jb      .L4
        sub     edx, r10d
        cmp     r9d, r10d
        lea     eax, [r8+r10]
        je      .L1
        mov     ecx, eax
        cmp     edx, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR buffer[0+rcx*4], eax
        lea     ecx, [rax+1]
        je      .L1
        mov     esi, ecx
        cmp     edx, 2
        mov     DWORD PTR buffer[0+rsi*4], ecx
        lea     ecx, [rax+2]
```

As you can see, this code has a lot of complicated moves and jumps and in general feels like a very complex way of performing a simple array initialization.

**Why is there such a big difference in the generated code?**

**Is the GCC C++-compiler better in general at optimizing code that is valid in both C and C++ when compared to the C-compiler?**

Comment: Additional data point: using `static unsigned int buffer[2048];` makes the C code similar too. You will have to actually use the `buffer` so that it does not get totally eliminated though. Looks like it's an alignment issue, the extra code is there to handle misalignment.

Comment: Identical syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics. Why do you expect the **different** languages C and C++ should generate the same code? This question is better asked in a gcc forum.

Comment: @Olaf maybe you could fill us in on the difference between semantics in C and C++ for this piece of code

Comment: In the C++ code, the inner loop is `.L2`. In C, it's `.L4`. They are more or less equivalent speedwise.

Comment: @Jester Pro tip for godbolt,  putting `void g(void *); g(buffer);` will prevent buffer being optimized out

Comment: @Olaf Why should it not ? If you have some specific insight into how and why gcc does what it does in this case, add an answer, as it's basically what what OP asks.

Comment: @M.M thanks for your pro tip, it's not like I had any problem doing it myself, in fact I had explicitly mentioned it has to be done ;)

Comment: Putting `unsigned int buffer[2048] = { 0 };` also generates the simpler code. Maybe Olaf is actually onto something  ,  in C `unsigned int buffer[2048]` is a *tentative definition*, something C++ doesn't have. This does not actually affect the observable behaviour of the program but obviously it has some influence on the GCC code generation.

Comment: @nos: I have not. It is not me assuming both veriants should generate the same code. One of many aspects could be the overal context which is not shown.

Comment: Just looks like it's inlining versus the C++ vectorization. Roughly counting this out it looks like C wins the match tbh. The rdx test value becomes 8192, and you loop at 64 bytes a time until that point so a total of 128 times. 128 * 5 (-1 for skipping the last jmp) = a lot more than the inlined C.

Comment: @jester that can be accomplished without using it by using the `volatile` keyword to tell the compiler not to remove it. i.e. `static volatile unsigned int buffer[2048];`

Comment: @CorvusCrypto yes but `volatile` also prohibits some optimizations (although not in this case)

Comment: correct. I meant in this case

Comment: Interesting, clang generates the same code for both situations.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The extra code is for handling misalignment because the instruction used, `vmovdqa64`, requires 64 byte alignment.

My testing shows that even though the standard doesn't, gcc does allow a definition in another module to override the one here when in C mode. That definition might only comply with the basic alignment requirements (4 bytes) thus the compiler can't rely on the bigger alignment. Technically, gcc emits a `.comm` assembly directive for this tentative definition, while an external definition uses a normal symbol in the `.data` section. During linking this symbol takes precedence over the `.comm` one.

Note if you change the program to use `extern unsigned int buffer[2048];` then even the C++ version will have the added code. Conversely, making it `static unsigned int buffer[2048];` will turn the C version into the optimized one.

Comment: There is no difference between C and C++ regarding linkage in this code. In both languages: (a) `buffer` has external linkage, (b) no other unit may *define* `buffer`, (c) other units may *declare* `buffer`.

Comment: "In the C case, the array may have a definition in another module" - that would be undefined behaviour in Standard C.  The discussion about linkage seems like a red herring, given that adding `= { 0 }` also produces the "optimized" version

Comment: Note, for compiling the C code version with gcc , you can add the `-fno-common` compiler flag, or annotate the `buffer` variable with `__attribute__((aligned(64)))` , and it will generate similar code to the C++ version.

Comment: @M.M actually this is a declaration, and it has external linkage in C but internal in C++. Having internal linkage means it must be defined in this module and the compiler will do that. For C, it may very well be defined in another module so the compiler might have to work with that. Of course adding an initializer will turn it into a definition and you can't have more of those in C either so the compiler can generate the optimized code.

Comment: gcc allows redefinition of the array tentative definition with lower alignment requirements , which isn't covered by the C standrad

Comment: @Jester Sorry but you are completely wrong. `unsigned int buffer[2048];` is a definition, and it has external linkage, in both languages.

Comment: @M.M. C calls that a "tentative definition", see e.g. C99 paragraph 6.9.2 , and allows more than one translation unit to contain the same definition - it's not undefined behavior to do so.

Comment: @nos Yes, "tentative definition" is a subset of "definition". I speculated about the interaction between tentative definitions and alignment in earlier comments

Comment: @M.M my old copy of the C standard says it is a declaration. This is further illustrated by the fact that you can have `unsigned int buffer[2048] = {1};` in another file and that will link properly, with the two `buffer` identifiers referring to the same memory and the definition coming from the second object file. If both were definitions as you claim, it wouldn't link.

Comment: @Jester It is a declaration, and a definition (all definitions are declarations).  Having two definitions in separate files is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required;  so receiving no diagnostic is not evidence to the contrary.  Luckily there are language standards so we know what the rules are, instead of trying to figure them out from behaviour of a particular compiler.  (Of course, perhaps gcc implements extensions beyond what the standards specify)

Comment: Okay I give you that it is a _tentative definition_ which basically means "definition with initializer 0 if there is no proper definition elsewhere, otherwise just a declaration". The point is still the same, there may be a proper definition with an initializer in another module and in that case this here is just a declaration referring to that definition, and the alignment is not under the compiler's control.

Comment: @Jester The tentative definition may only be redefined within the same translation unit. A tentative definition is a definition, not "just a declaration" in any circumstance. Your point is still wrong in Standard C.

Comment: The longer I look at it, the more it seems like you are correct. However, intentionally or not, but gcc allows the tentative definition to be overridden by an initializer from a different module and that will pull its own alignment with it. Given that it's undefined behavior this may thus change with later versions but for the version in the question this seems to be the case.

Comment: Allowing definitions with no initializer in multiple translation units is a Unix extension (which is an odd concept, since Unix had C for nearly 20 years before ANSI came along) which (I believe is still) used in GNU programs.  I find it highly unlikely that GCC would actually drop support for it, even the ANSI standard technically allows it.